# Why does the as.Date function in R converts the years I enter into the current year 2020?

Tags: r, as.date

I have some dates in a dataframe, and when I use as.Date() to convert them into dates, the years convert into 2020, which isn't really valid because the file only has data up to 2018.

What I have so far:

```
> fechadeinsc1[2]
[1] "2020-08-15"

> class(fechadeinsc1)
[1] "Date"

> fechainsc[2]
[1] "2017/99/99"

> class(fechainsc)
[1] "character"
```

As you can see, fechadeinsc1 was converted into a date and fechainsc is the original dataframe which elements are characters. "fechadeinsc1" should give the same year, shouldn't it? Even though days and months aren't valid.

**Another example**:

```
> fechadenac1[2]
[1] "2020-12-31"

> class(fechadenac1)
[1] "Date"

> fechanac[2]
[1] "12/31/2016"

> class(fechanac)
[1] "character"
```

Again, the year changes.

**My code**:

```
fechanac <- dat$fecha_nac
fechainsc <- dat$fecha_insc

fechadeinsc1 <- as.Date(fechainsc,tryFormats =c("%d/%m/%y","%m/%d/%y","%y","%d%m%y","%m%d%y"))
fechadenac1 <- as.Date(fechanac,tryFormats =c("%d/%m/%y","%m/%d/%y","%y","%d%m%y","%m%d%y"))
```

"dat" is the original dataframe which contains information about newborns registered in 2016 and 2017 in Ecuador, if anyone wants the original .csv file please contact me.

Comment: Try with `anydate` from `anytime` `anydate(c("2020-08-15", "12/31/2016"))
[1] "2020-08-15" "2016-12-31"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [`strptime`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/strptime), referred from [`as.Date`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/as.Date), you should use upper case Y for 4-digit years:

> `%y` Year without century (00--99). On input, values 00 to 68 are prefixed by 20 and 69 to 99 by 19 -- that is the behaviour specified by the 2004 and 2008 POSIX standards, but they do also say ‘it is expected that in a future version the default century inferred from a 2-digit year will change’.

> `%Y` Year with century. [...]

Comment: Any idea on how to get rid of the /99/99? I mean how can I only save or use the year?

Comment: You can check if `tryFormats` accepts a pattern like `"%Y/99/99"`, practically treating the /99/99 part as some kind of weird separator.